# Android app install verification

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have an app which list some campaigns(list of apps) that user can install and earn the points. Now here my main concern is security. some of the user installing the apps either from emulator or vpn or something else so that my client is not getting app installs in google play store.

i have seen some apps like cash pirate,app money etc which does not give points if campaign is installed through emulator.

how can i verify that campaign is installed through phone or emulator or `vpn`.

***NOTE :*** I have already checked `Build Model`,`manufacturer` etc for emulator!!

Any advance help would be appreciated !!!

Comment: i am already checking build model,manufacturer etc for emulator

Comment: A workaround method is to detect some hardware features that the emulator don't have.

Comment: thats what i am looking for....any kernel/hardware related info.....

Comment: camera, location provider, wifi features etc.

Comment: i am not sure any patch is there for all the above features...like play store in genymotion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found below link to detect some kernel things in emulator. I don't know it will help me or not...but just for the sake of info, I shared here

https://www.airpair.com/android/posts/adding-tampering-detection-to-your-android-app

Code

```
public static boolean checkEmulator() {
    try {
        boolean goldfish = getSystemProperty("ro.hardware").contains("goldfish");
        boolean emu = getSystemProperty("ro.kernel.qemu").length() > 0;
        boolean sdk = getSystemProperty("ro.product.model").equals("sdk");

        if (emu || goldfish || sdk) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    return false;
}
```